# NGRX effects with rxjs delay operator

Tags: ngrx

I have a code looking like this in an angular project using ngrx 16.2.0

```js
@Injectable()
export class aEffects {

  aActionEffect$ = createEffect(() => {
      return this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(aAction),
        map(() => aActionSuccess())
      );
    }
  );

  aActionSuccessEffect$ = createEffect(() => {
      return this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(aActionSuccess),
        delay(1000),
        map(() => bAction)
      );
    }
  );

  constructor(
    protected readonly actions$: Actions
  ) {
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class bEffects {
  bActionEffect$ = createEffect(() => {
      return this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(bAction),
        switchMap(() => {
          return bService.doAsynchronousTask().pipe(
            map(() => bActionSuccess();
          );
        })
      );
    }
  );

  constructor(
    protected readonly actions$: Actions,
    protected readonly bService: BService,
  ) {
  }
}
```

When the delay is on, i have this sequence of actions showing in redux dev tools:

1. aAction
2. aActionSucess
3. bActionSuccess
4. (delay)
5. bAction

Where obviously, i'm waiting for:

1. aAction
2. aActionSucess
3. (delay)
4. bAction
5. bActionSuccess

The last sequence is the one i get once i remove the delay.

It oes not appear to be a problem of log sequence, the network shows that bService is called without delay.

I cannot find examples of working code.
If you see anything which is not by the book, I'm interested.

My next step will be to build a simple app to reproduce the bug to verify if it is related to ngrx and not my app.

Thanks!

Comment: from the code you provide that does not seem possible

Comment: Can you add you actions to the questions? Did you make a copy past error - same strings? Because i agree with @Andrei, it's impossible from the effect code